# How to make counter count in multiple methods in java?

Tags: java

A robot starts at location (0,0) facing east. Several beeper stacks are randomly placed along that row, each containing a number of beepers. A robot starts at location (0,0) facing east. Several beeper stacks are randomly placed along that row, each containing a number of beepers. There may be different numbers of beepers stacks. But there is always a beeper stack at location (0,0) and always a beeper stack at location (16,0)-(the end of robot world).

Need to write a method that makes the robot move along the row, picking up each beeper stack as it goes. The method should return no value and take no parameters.
After the robot has picked up the last stack, the program should print how many beepers were picked up in total. 
The message should look like this: Picked up n beepers,
where n is the number of beepers picked up.
The program must define and use these two additional methods:
moveRobotToNextStack() , which moves the robot forwards until it finds the next stack
and
pickUpBeeperStack(), which picks up all the beepers in a stack.
My code:

```
public class Q4 {
void pickUpAllStacks() {
    int counter=0;
       pickUpBeeperStack();
       moveRobotToNextStack();
      counter += pickUpBeeperStack();
       print("Picked up "+ counter +" beepers");

    }

void moveRobotToNextStack() { 
        while(isSpaceInFrontOfRobotClear()) {
            moveRobotForwards();
            pickUpBeeperStack(); 
        }

    }  

    int pickUpBeeperStack() {
        int counter=0;
        while(isItemOnGroundAtRobot()) {
            pickUpItemWithRobot();
            counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
}
```

I can't make counter count beepers in all stacks.

Comment: you can use a static int counter and increment its value inside your methods

Comment: Sounds like you want to put "private int counter=0;" outside all the functions and remove it from inside the functions.

Comment: So, if I understood it right you want to increment `counter` in method `pickUpBeeperStack()` and `pickUpAllStacks()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `counter` as object level variable:

```
int counter=0;

void pickUpAllStacks() {
       pickUpBeeperStack();
       moveRobotToNextStack();
      counter += pickUpBeeperStack();
       print("Picked up "+ counter +" beepers");

    }

void moveRobotToNextStack() { 
        while(isSpaceInFrontOfRobotClear()) {
            moveRobotForwards();
            pickUpBeeperStack(); 
        }

    }  

    int pickUpBeeperStack() {

        while(isItemOnGroundAtRobot()) {
            pickUpItemWithRobot();
            counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Cheers !!

Comment: but in your code - `counter` is not class level variable its object level. it seems you wanted to declare that as `static`